# Slow Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 14.04, system

I'm new for linux, but I had some occasion to use different versions of it on other PCs or live-CD on my own PC.

Yesterday I decided to normally install Ubuntu on my desktop computer after several sucks with Windows 7.

My problem is, that the installed system is very slow, slow response time (destop search delayes 1-2 seconds when I type characters!), the videos (in youtube) are slow (others not yet working), etc. ANd the window in the Gnome/Kde (default) environment is slow by moving, resizing, opening, closing, etc.

The system has following parameters:

- Amd X2 processor (64bit) dual core at 2.3 Ghz
- 2 Gb system memory (therof 1,8 Gb usable due to integrated AMD/ATI X1200 series video card)
- Corsair SSD accelarator (used as single SSD without HDD), read / write is about 200/ 150 Mb/sec.

Default install and updates from internet was done. The processor use in average is about 70-95% each, without running nothing. In system monitor I see a kind of graphic program running and consuming 30-50% CPU time in average, if I close this the desktop tray and icons disappers and CPU useage fall back ca 20-30% per core each (but nothing works after it).

What could be the problem? How I could fix it?  Now this Ubuntu is slower on this computer as a Windows 7 on a 10 years laptop.... Ubuntu version is 14.04, the latest.

I checked a kind of system properties and drivers panel, it is said up to date.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Although you've got a 64-bit processor, if you're only running 2Gb of RAM it might be worth trying the 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks, Ok, I will give a try later for 32 bit, but I wonder why a PC so slow under Linux and fast under Win 7, I imagined that Windows 7 is slow, Linux is fast....

Comment: I guess Ubuntu now has a lot more features than versions from years ago so is a little more demanding. I don't know your situation, but putting in RAM would almost certainly speed things up and probably allow you to make full use of your 64-bit processor with Ubuntu 64. If you can afford it I'd say stick some more RAM in for a worthwhile upgrade! Good luck all the same!

Comment: Thank you! Increasing memory for technical reason not possible: either not supported above 2 Gb, or max. 4 Gb supported, but the current 2*1  gb should be raplaced by 2*2 gb, which is not worth to do. I will try something from software side. Surprising that Win 7 runs smoothly but Ubuntu not :-)

Answer (score 0):

Disable automatic startup of any services that are not needed (or even remove the package completely).

A lot of packages startup services automatically. These services then use memory and CPU even they are hardly ever used. It is better in this case, to stop those services, or take them out of autostart, and start them up only if they are needed.

To remove applications from starting up on 10.04,go to System > Preferences > Startup Applications (may be slightly different on other versions)

On 12.04, you can go select the startup applications by clicking on the Dash Icon. Then, type startup and select "startup applications".

[image]

And just unmark the apps you don't need. But be sure about it, don't just remove apps you don't know. If you are not sure about one, leave it that way. A google search or new question here about specific programs will help.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it first, but I do not think it will help a lot. The most processor power consuming process is the graphical interface process (ca. 50% of both cores), if I kill it, the desktop closes. I guess that any graphic driver or something related to display/graphic card could solve the problem. It seems that graphic card / display management is slow (typing, windows on desktop, etc.), and also slow reaction time, despite of the SSD.

Comment: you are right , Your big mistake is 64bit OS, 
You have to be come down , 32bit is a good choice .

Comment: Thanks! 64 bit was not decided by me, but the automatic download decided for it, when I downloaded it on this PC under Win 7. I will try the 32 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu website recommendation do not detects your hardware ,
Simply they recommend 64bit for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try Lubuntu, which is designed for low-spec hardware.

And as Duck Hunt said, it would be better to use a 32-bits version.

Comment: OK, thanks. Later I will try it, if other options do not work. Maybe it helps, and I can use Linux, but now I am wondering how fast computer needed for Linux, 5/10 years ago when I used Linux mostly they were notably faster and lower resource demanding as Windows versions.